# how to compare values in variables against strings

Tags: php, html, forms

i have the following code but it dosen't seem to work

the html:

```
    <input class="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio_group_1" value="Male">
    <label for class="gender_male" ="radio_1">Male</label>  

    <input class="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio_group_1" value="Female"> 
    <label for class="gender_female" ="radio_2">Female</label>
```

the php:

```
  $gender=mysqli_escape_string($db,$_POST['radio_group_1']);//gender
```

the following code dosen't seem to work

```
 if($gender=="male")
{
$profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/male.jpg";
}
if($gender=="female")
{
$profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/female.jpg";
 }
```

Comment: HTML values are capitalized, but you're checking against lowercase in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this ..
Case Sensitivity is the problem

```
    if($gender=="Male")
{
$profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/male.jpg";
}
if($gender=="Female")
{
$profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/female.jpg";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, case sensitivity is the issue here.

To avoid issues with case sensitivity you can use [strcmp](https://www.php.net/strcmp). Using this function will compare 2 strings and return 0 if they match.

```
if(strcmp($gender, "Male") == 0)
{
    $profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/male.jpg";
}

if(strcmp($gender, "Female") == 0)
{
    $profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/female.jpg";
}
```

You might also consider a [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement and make your text lowercase first using [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

```
switch(strtolower($gender))
{
    case "male": $profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/male.jpg"; break;
    case "female": $profile_photo = "profile_photo_encrypt/female.jpg"; break;
}
```